# ng2-dragula gives error after navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-dragula

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-logout',
    template: ''
})
export class Logouts implements OnInit{

    constructor(private path:Router){

    }

    ngOnInit(){ 

        localStorage.clear();
        this.path.navigate(['./login']);
    }


}
```

Hi i am using ng2-dragula for drag and drop. it is working perfectly. But when i am clicking the logout link it redirect to logout component. where i clear the local storage. then navigate to login page.but it gives error when i click on link
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Bag named: "bag1" already exists.
    here is my logout component code
but i am not using any bag1 on logout component.i am using that bag1 on different component. i do not know what is the exact issue. please help me.

Comment: i think this issue is comming because i am not destroying the bag. because on login page i am using the only one bag bag1 for drag and drop. after login if i am not destroying the bag the it gives error when i come again on login page after logout.

Comment: but when i am destroying the bag just after login in ngOnDestroy() then it gives error like can not read property of drake. please help me . i think i am missing some thing..